# Abstractive Text summarization using T5 pre-trained model

Tags: huggingface-transformers, summarization

Hello I'm using t5 pretrained abstractive summarization how I can evaluate the summary output accuracy IN short how much percent my model are accurate

Comment: You can use an [summarization dataset](http://nlpprogress.com/english/summarization.html).

Answer (score 1):

You could use ROUGE Metric as its metric for automatic summarization evaluation.

https://pypi.org/project/rouge-metric/